# Adding Color to tableview, and cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to be able to change the background color  (the view behind the cells) of a UITableView. I tried the following ;

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0f/255.0f green:230.0f/255.0f blue:230.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

What hapens here is that the cells also turn to the above color.

1.) I need the cells to be in another color, and the background of the tableView (When the you scroll the view right up, you will see the background of the tableview- the default color of the tableview is white) to be in a different color.

2.) I have successfully colored the cells of my tableview, i have also added a disclosure arrows, but it shows up in a white background as shown in this [image](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Z5XcQgOc4Ao/TtY_qdXsbjI/AAAAAAAAAJE/Uqy6i8M5ulg/s1600/Screen+Shot+2011-11-30+at+15.36.58.png). i need it too to have the same color as the cell. I undestand that i have to add a custom disclosure arrows but i don't know how to do it programatically. Can someone help me here ?

Answer (score 1):

1) From the UITableViewCell documentation:

> Note: If you want to change the background color of a cell (by setting
>   the background color of a cell via the backgroundColor property
>   declared by UIView) you must do it in the
>   tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of the delegate
>   and not in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the data source.
>   Changes to the background colors of cells in a group-style table view
>   has an effect in iOS 3.0 that is different than previous versions of
>   the operating system. It now affects the area inside the rounded
>   rectangle instead of the area outside of it.

2)
Have you tried setting the background color of cell.accessoryView?